# Best way of running two threads alternatively?

Tags: java, concurrency

**Update: see bottom of this question for a complete answer.**

I want to run a secondary thread, so that my main thread and my secondary thread perform operations alternatively (no, I don't want to do all the operations in the main thread, it is for a unit test).

I came up to two different solutions, I don't know which is the best, and I have questions regarding the first one:

### Using Exchanger

I came up to something using an [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) (while I don't want to exchange only one object).

```
@Test
public void launchMyTest() {
    /**
     * An anonymous class to set some variables from a different thread
     */
    class ThreadTest extends Thread {
        //declare some various attributes that will be set
        //NOT DECLARED VOLATILE
        ...

        public final Exchanger<Integer> exchanger = new Exchanger<Integer>();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //start of the synchronization 
                int turn = 1;
                while (turn != 2) {
                    turn = this.exchanger.exchange(turn);
                }

                //do some work and set my various variables
                ...

                //main thread's turn
                turn = 1;
                this.exchanger.exchange(turn);
                //wait for this thread's turn
                while (turn != 2) {
                    turn = this.exchanger.exchange(turn);
                }

                //redo some other work and reset the various variables
                ...

                //main thread's turn
                turn = 1;
                this.exchanger.exchange(turn);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } 
        }
    }


    try {
        //some work in the main thread
        ....

        //launch the job in the second thread
        ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
        test.start();
        //start of the synchronization
        int turn = 2;
        test.exchanger.exchange(turn);
        //wait for this thread's turn
        while (turn != 1) {
            turn = test.exchanger.exchange(turn);
        }

        //run some tests using the various variables of the anonymous class
        ....

        //now, relaunch following operations in the second thread
        turn = 2;
        test.exchanger.exchange(turn);
        //wait for this thread's turn
        while (turn != 1) {
            turn = test.exchanger.exchange(turn);
        }

        //do some other tests using the various variables of the anonymous class
        //...

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

#### Question:

- Am I correct that the `exchange` method performs memory synchronization, just as much as using a `Lock`?

### Using Condition

Another solution using a [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html):

```
@Test
public void launchMyTest() {
    /**
     * An anonymous class to set some variables from a different thread
     */
    class ThreadTest extends Thread {
        //declare some various attributes that will be set
        //NOT DECLARED VOLATILE
        ...

        public final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        public final Condition oneAtATime = lock.newCondition();
        public int turn = 1;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.lock.lock();
            try {
                //do some work and set my various variables
                ...

                //main thread's turn
                this.turn = 1;
                this.oneAtATime.signal();

                //wait for this thread's turn
                while (this.turn != 2) {
                    this.oneAtATime.await();
                }

                //redo some other work and reset the various variables
                ...

                //main thread's turn
                this.turn = 1;
                this.oneAtATime.signal();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                this.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }


    ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
    test.lock.lock();
    try {
        //some work in the main thread
        ....

        //launch the job in the second thread
        test.turn = 2;
        test.start();
        //wait for this thread's turn
        while (test.turn != 1) {
            test.oneAtATime.await();
        }

        //run some tests using the various variables of the anonymous class
        ....

        //now, relaunch following operations in the second thread
        test.turn = 2;
        test.oneAtATime.signal();
        //wait for this thread's turn
        while (test.turn != 1) {
            test.oneAtATime.await();
        }

        //do some other tests using the various variables of the anonymous class
        //...

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        test.lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

It seems to me a bit more complicated.

### Conclusion

What do you think is the best solution? Am I doing it right, or do I miss another obvious solution?

I didn't use a `CountDownLatch` as I want to run **several** operations alternatively, and the `CountDownLatch` cannot be reset. And I didn't find that the `CyclicBarrier` was making the code simpler... (actually I didn't totally understand how to use it, but it didn't look simpler than using `Exchanger` or `Condition`)

Thank you.

### Update

@Clément MATHIEU provided different examples of how to achieve this, in comments of its [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326551/1768736), see: https://gist.github.com/cykl/5131021

There are three examples, one using a `CyclicBarrier`, another one using an `Exchanger`, and a last one using 2 `Semaphore`s. While he is right to say that the "more expressive is the semaphore based one", I chose to use an `Exchanger` for simplicity. My unit test became:

```
@Test
public void launchMyTest() {
    /**
     * An anonymous class to set some variables from a different thread
     */
    class ThreadTest extends Thread {
        //declare some various attributes that will be set
        //NOT DECLARED VOLATILE
        ...
        public final Exchanger<Integer> exchanger = new Exchanger<Integer>();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //do some work and set my various variables
                ...

                //main thread's turn
                this.exchanger.exchange(null);
                //wait for this thread's turn
                this.exchanger.exchange(null);

                //redo some other work and reset the various variables
                ...

                //main thread's turn
                this.exchanger.exchange(null);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } 
        }
    }


    try {
        //some work in the main thread
        ....

        //launch the job in the second thread
        ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
        test.start();
        //wait for this thread's turn
        test.exchanger.exchange(null);

        //run some tests using the various variables of the anonymous class
        ....

        //now, relaunch following operations in the second thread
        test.exchanger.exchange(null);
        //wait for this thread's turn
        test.exchanger.exchange(null);

        //do some other tests using the various variables of the anonymous class
        //...

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Executors.

Comment: Don't have a look at Executors, or don't do any of the proposed solutions? :p

Comment: And if I understand `Exchanger` correctly, what it does is block either of two threads accessing it until the other one attempts the exchange, then they swap items, then they both run again. So it definitely won't do what you want to do. I'm guessing you actually want a plain old pair of semaphores. I.e. when the thread T1 finishes an operation, it signals S2, waits on S1, and vice versa.

Comment: Also this sounds like the kind of thing that might be covered in college-level material. Poke around an operating systems textbook?

Comment: @millimoose: Nonconstructive comments. "You should concentrate on how to achieve your high-level goal correctly" => As said, I need to unit test the acquisition of a shared resource from another thread. "So it definitely won't do what you want to do" => except that in my code, I immediately reswap to obtain the desired goal... "when the thread T1 finishes an operation, it signals S2, waits on S1, and vice versa" => yes it is exactly what I need, so could you come up with a better suggestion than mine? This is the whole point of this question :)

Comment: Would Object.wait() and Object.notify() not work?

Comment: It would. But I read once that it was like programming in assembler ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct that the exchange method performs memory synchronization, just as much as using a Lock?

You are right. The javadoc specifies there is a happen-before relation:

"*Memory consistency effects: For each pair of threads that successfully exchange objects via an Exchanger, actions prior to the exchange() in each thread happen-before those subsequent to a return from the corresponding exchange() in the other thread.*"

> What do you think is the best solution?

Both are equivalent. You should target expressiveness. I find the synchronisation/Lock/Monitor based solution more expressive than the exchanged based one. But it does not really matter if you abstract this code in a dedicated class.

> Am I doing it right, or do I miss another obvious solution?

AFAIK no If you don't want to re-implement the wheel.

Please note that your ReentrantLock based solution can also be written using plain old synchronisation or Monitor from Guava.

See: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Monitor.html for a comparison.

> And I didn't find that the CyclicBarrier was making the code simpler... (actually I didn't totally understand how to use it, but it didn't look simpler than using

CyclicBarrier does not fit your needs. It is not designed for mutual exclusion;  it allows a set of threads to define a common barrier. Threads will execute concurrently and wait for each other at some point before moving to the next step.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. "actions prior to the exchange() in each thread happen-before" => does it mean that I don't need the two blocks of code below `//start of the synchronization`? I thought that I needed to define a kind of "synchronisation starting point", in the same way we acquire a lock before `await`ing on a `Condition`. It would seem weird to me not to define one.

Comment: About the `CyclicBarrier` it is because in the javadoc for [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), they say: "the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a `CyclicBarrier`." A `CountDownLatch` that could be reset would be exactly what I need. A `CyclicBarrier` is *not* simply a `CountDownLatch` that can be reset for what I see...

Comment: A CountDownLatch allows one shot synchronization; it cannot be reset. It allows one or more thread to wait until a set of operation completes. A CyclicBarrier is more general; it allows a set of thread to wait for each other at a given point

Comment: I just quickly wrote three examples using an Exchanger, an CyclicBarrier and two Semaphores to be sure that you grasp the concept. I did not wrote an example using a ReentrantLock or a Monitor but it should be quite similar. All theses implementations should work and are quite similar. IMHO the cleanest and more expressive is the semaphore based one. See: https://gist.github.com/cykl/5131021

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples, notably for the `Semaphore`! A few questions: when using the `CyclicBarrier`, shouldn't you call `reset()` at the end of the loop running the `r2` thread? (otherwise it means that the barrier is reset each time the threads cross the barrier?) - About the `Semaphore`, wouldn't it be exactly the same as `CyclicBarrier` if you were using only one `Semaphore` with two permits?

Comment: You don't have to call `reset` (and must not). The barrier is automatically reset when the current generation is full. That is why the barrier is cyclic. See `dowait` and `nextGeneration` in the OpenJDK implementation. Since you want a strict round robin behavior, I don't see any robust solution using only one semaphore even with the fair behavior flag enabled. I updated the gist to add `SingleSemaphoreHack` which is an ugly hack that will break as soon as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is reached. It's for educational purpose only, try to understand why you have to play with the number of permits.

Comment: I understood why when trying to write an example using only one `new Semaphore(0)`. I still have a concern regarding the `Exchanger` example, line 61, `r1.run()`: I understand that this will `happen-before` the `exchange`. But will there be a memory synchronization on all variables set before, even non-`volatile`? I have hard time to imagine not having a starting point, where to say: "start memory sync here", like entering a `synchronized` block. This is what I did in the first example of my question (I accepted your answer and updated my question to point to your comments, thx a lot!)

Comment: You should give a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), section **Memory Consistency Properties**. _For each pair of threads that successfully exchange objects via an Exchanger, actions prior to the exchange() in each thread happen-before those subsequent to the corresponding exchange() in another thread._.

Comment: just because the happens before hapens does not mean all vars are updated to the main memory. JVMs might decicde they not shared. so the shared vars should be volatile.

Comment: Ha, this is what I'm wondering. I couldn't find the answer with a quick search.

Comment: @tgkprog: You are wrong. The JMM and Exchanger documentation clearly states that *any* memory operations which were visible before the exchange are visible to the other thread after the exchange.

Comment: So this is what "happen-before" means? Guarantee of memory synchronization?

Comment: @clement-mathieu did you watch the youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVooKLLVT8 ? Djebel what did you finally use? did you get to test on a multi core server with different implementations to see if it fails ever?

Answer (score 2):

exchanger looks right. After watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVooKLLVT8 I think the variable should be volatile, says there is hardly any over head.

Answer (score 0):

The locking mechanism is directly addressing the task you are performing here by focusing on the mutual exclusions of the locks so my recommendation is for that approach.

Comment: Is there any benefit to the first solution compared to the second one? It looks weird to use an `Exchanger` not to exchange anything, so maybe the second one is more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven’t used `Exchanger` yet, it looks like it’s the simplest solution for what you want to achieve. Less code than the much more general `Lock`/`Condition` version. As for the memory consistency: That's what they promise [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).