# How to create a cyclic exchange of three threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to create a cyclic exchange of three threads? That is: *first* thread must send data to *second*, *second* to *third* and *third* thread must send data to *first*.

I wrote some code, but threads exchange in random oder.

```
class DataClass {

    int value;
    String message;

    DataClass(int v, String s) {
        value = v;
        message = s;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return (value);
    }

    String getMassage() {
        return (message);
    }
}

class Loop implements Runnable {

    int counter;
    String name;
    Exchanger<DataClass> exchanger;

    Loop(int startValue, String id, Exchanger<DataClass> ex) {
        counter = startValue;
        name = id;
        exchanger = ex;
        System.out.println(name + ": created");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + ": started");

        DataClass data = new DataClass(counter, name);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            try {
                DataClass newData = exchanger.exchange(data);
                counter += newData.getValue();

                System.out.println(name + ": from "
                        + newData.getMassage() + ": data: "
                        + newData.getValue() + ": state = " + counter);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(name + ": ended");
    }
}

public class ExchangerDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Main process started");
        Exchanger<DataClass> exchanger = new Exchanger<DataClass>();
        Loop loop1 = new Loop(1, "First", exchanger);
        Loop loop2 = new Loop(2, "Second", exchanger);
        Loop loop3 = new Loop(3, "Third", exchanger);
        new Thread(loop1).start();
        new Thread(loop2).start();
        new Thread(loop3).start();
        System.out.println("Main process ended");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass a reference of a thread to the next.

Comment: And how I can implements it use this reference?

Comment: You have `Loop loop1`, pass it in the Constructor for the next loop or use a setter since it's circular dependency.

Comment: That I need pass a reference of a thread to the next I understand. But I don`t understand how use it in run, for exchange data.

That something like:
 if (this.name.equals("Third") && this.next.equals("Firs")) 
Or not?

Comment: Yes something like that, but you wouldn't start the Threads until they were properly initialized. Also, you're in a multithreaded environment so take proper precautions with `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

For your dependency you should make three classes, and have three distinct Exchange objects (one in each). So thread1 would be between 1 and 2 (output of 1 to 2), thread 2's would be between 2 and 3 and thread 3's exhanger would be between itself and 1. Remember the exchanger's would guard only until it had its input from its feeder, to till it passes to its receiver.

Also synchronized is not as bad as the books make out. use it. Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVooKLLVT8

Also for reference [Best way of running two threads alternatively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324631/best-way-of-running-two-threads-alternatively/15327234#15327234)

Also why do you need three threads? Can you use a thread pool and have each task to the 3 things ?

Comment: I need three threads because this is the task.
Thank you for helping. 
Now try do as your advice, but I don`t fully understand your idea adout 
  //"So thread1 would be between 1 and 2 (output of 1 to 2), thread 2's would be between 2 and 3 and thread 3's exhanger would be between itself and 1. "//

Can you show me an example please?